# How to fix: the python code doesn't work through DAG airflow: pandas.read_csv('gs://x/y.csv') file doesn't exist

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

the code on my computer runs fine but when I put it in DAG to run through Airflow it doesn't work. I use GCP and composer. The other tasks work fine on the same cloud storage. The composer has all permissions needed.

```
def get_results():
    import pandas as pandas
    df = pandas.read_csv('gs://y/x.csv')

with models.DAG(
        ...) as dag:
     search_simmilar = python_operator.PythonOperator(
         task_id='search',
         python_callable=get_results
     )
```

Error in Airflow logs:

```
File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_sourc
FileNotFoundError: File b'gs://y/x.csv' does not exis
```

Comment: This may just be in your question (rather than your actual code), but you need a comma between the gcs path and the header parameter.

Comment: @AdamHopkinson good eye but there is comma in my code, just here i made mistake. Furthermore I tried df = pandas.read_csv('gs://y/x.csv') without other parameters

Answer (score 1):

GCP composer uses Cloud Storage FUSE which maps your composer dag folder to the `Google cloud storage` bucket in which you place your DAGs (e.g.: `gs://bucket-name/dags`).

I advise you to place your files that are shared between dags in this folder `/home/airflow/gcs/data` which is mapped to `gs://bucket-name/dags`. Here you can read more about `Google cloud storage` and `Composer`: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage

Also here's an example:

```
import os
import pandas as pandas

def get_results():
    path_to_csv = os.path.join('/home/airflow/gcs/data', 'y','x.csv') 
    df = pandas.read_csv(path_to_csv, header=None)

with models.DAG(
        ...) as dag:
     search_simmilar = python_operator.PythonOperator(
         task_id='search',
         python_callable=get_results
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the pandas version installed in your composer.
Pandas version [0.24.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html) Added support for reading from/writing to Google Cloud Storage via the gcsfs library

NOTE: upgrading the pandas version may broke the existing operators, as the hooks would be using or depends on the older pandas version.
Eg. BigQueryOperator will fail due to pandas dependency.
In that case you can choose to use PythonVirtualenvOperator or KubernetesPodOperator, where you can able to install the dependant modules(like pandas >0.24.0) without affecting the existing environment.

Comment: I tried: 
`    split = python_operator.PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id='split',
        python_callable=split_set,
        requirements=['pandas==0.24.2']
    )`


ERROR - Command '['/tmp/venvs80fvb9n/bin/python', '/tmp/venvs80fvb9n/script.py', '/tmp/venvs80fvb9n/script.in', '/tmp/venvs80fvb9n/script.out', '/tmp/venvs80fvb9n/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways of solving this:

- Easy way

  - put the CSV file in the `dags` folder along with your `DAG.py` file.
  - Composer automagically maps its directory structure to GCS on creation as indicated by viewing the `airflow.cfg`

    - you can find this file by looking up one level in your `DAGs folder` in [GCP Console Composer](https://console.cloud.google.com/composer/environments)
  - access the file by using the path `/home/airflow/gcs/dags/<path>/<to>/<file>.csv`
- Harder way (use an existing [operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e62ad5333cbb56ae0f2001f0f79008a21c41a983/airflow/contrib/operators/s3_to_gcs_operator.py) as an example)

  - create a [gcs_hook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e62ad5333cbb56ae0f2001f0f79008a21c41a983/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.py)
  - run `GoogleCloudStorageHook.download(bucket, object)`
  - (optional) save byte string as a `NamedTemporaryFile`
  - read this file or byte string into pandas

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Variable, go to Dashboard -> Admin -> Variables, create a new variable with your gc bucket. For example I use for the key: gcs_bucket and for val: gs://your_unique_key
2. In dag file import:

```
import datetime
from airflow import models

output_file = os.path.join(models.Variable.get('gcs_bucket'), 'directory_name',
                           datetime.datetime.now().strftime(%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)) + '.csv'
```